# Media keys Next and Previous don't work in safari

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, music, catalina

If I play music via safari (YouTube music or soundcloud.com) I can't skip the song or move to the previous one using media keys on MacBook or Bluetooth keyboard.

Stop/Start buttons work well, as well as fast forward and fast backward, but I can't skip the song or move to the previous one.

Is it expected behavior or it's a bug(because in google chrome it works)?

Safari Version: 13.0.3 (15608.3.10.1.4)
MacOS Catalina Version: 10.15.1 (19B88)
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Answer (score 1):

For a test, play a YouTube video in Safari and go to Notification Centre, and find "Now Playing". What the arrow keys do here is what the physical keys would do too. In Safari, they're for fast forward. I don't have chrome, so you can test what they do there.

For Spotify, they are used to skip songs.

[image]

Comment: yes, buttons from Notification Center works in the same way as physical media keys - Play/Pause and Fast Forward / Backward (if press the button and hold) work but Play Next / Prev doesn't work.

Comment: I meant to say that, it is expected behaviour.